# shuffling numbers in array

Tags: java, swap

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double[] myList=new double[10];
        System.out.println("enter values");
        for (int i = 1; i < myList.length; i++) {
            java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
            int j = (int)Math.random() * myList.length;
            double tmp=myList[j];
            myList[i]=myList[j];
            myList[j]=tmp;
            System.out.println(tmp);    
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it printing `0.0`?

Comment: You never put any values in your array. You're just swapping a bunch of `0.0` doubles around.

Comment: did you use `Scanner` object `input` (created 10 times) even once? The default value of int type is 0

Comment: Could you provide us with more information other than a method and its output?

Comment: @LukeMelaia The title really does speak for itself, and the body gives a bit more context (But yes, I agree more information would be useful)

Answer (score 0):

doubles and integers are intialized as 0, so your array is actually 10 zeros.

You need a few things:

```
double[] myList=new double[10];
System.out.println("enter values");
java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    myList[i] = input.nextDouble();// get input from user and put it into array
}
//and then we swap
for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    int j = (int)Math.random() * myList.length;
    double tmp=myList[j];
    myList[i]=myList[j];
    myList[j]=tmp;
}
System.out.println(tmp);
```

There were a few problems:

1. Your `Scanner` wasn't being used at all, and you created it 10 times (because it was in the loop)
2. You didn't initialize the array, so all the values are `0.0`
3. You started looping at index 1, so you miss out some values

Comment: downvoter, please elaborate

Comment: This is for the down voter: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions/255861#255861

Comment: @user3437460 wow. thanks so much (this isn't ironic at all I've been searching the meta for something like that for at least a month)

Comment: You are welcomed. I just encountered a similar issue like you. Someone down voted my solution because my answer was too detailed. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288154/downvoted-for-giving-a-detailed-answer

Answer (score 0):

if you want to really swipe the values than loop should be as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    int j = (int)Math.random() * myList.length;
    double tmp=myList[i];
    myList[i]=myList[j];
    myList[j]=tmp;
}
```